# prevstate in `this.setState` -- a copy or a reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and haven't come across the correct answer.

In the following code:

```
this.setState(prevState => counter: prevState.counter + 1);
```

is `prevState` a reference to the current state? Or is it a copy of it? Is it fine to mutate or should mutating it be avoided?

Comment: You can easily check it: console.log(prevState === this.state). If it is true, then it is the same reference.

Comment: That is explained very well in [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documents...

> prevState is a reference to the previous state. It should not be
>   directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a
>   new object based on the input from prevState and props.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

So to answer your question, prevState is the state before the last mutation occurred.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. I was looking at the state & lifecycle page in the docs, not the react component page. d'oh